# Rule to Maximize Cash Back Returns

Tags: percentages

This is all curiosity. It's just something that's been stuck in my head today, and I thought I'd throw it out there.

With my Amazon rewards card, I get 3% cash back on purchases from Amazon, 1% on everywhere else (ok, 2% some places, but irrelevant right now). I've figured out the following:

```
Final Cost = Sale Price - (Sale Price * Cash Back)
```

To figure out whether I should buy an item off of Amazon or, say, pick it up at Wal-Mart, I can just pick the minimum of Final Cost A and Final Cost B, or `min(FA,FB)`. This is simple enough. What I'm wondering is if there's another way of framing this that just compares the distance between the two Sale Prices `(SA, SB)`. In other words, there's got to be a point at which the Amazon price reaches a threshold where, despite the larger amount of cash back, it still costs more than the alternative product. And maybe there's a formula or rule that, assuming the cash back rates remain constant, only requires me to determine whether SA is within a certain distance of SB to know which is actually less expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get $3\%$ back, you final price is $0.97$ times the sale price, so compare $0.97$ times the Amazon price to $0.99$ times the Wal-Mart price.  If you only want to multiply once, you can divide the two coefficients and compare $0.979797979797979797$ times the Amazon price to the basic Wal-Mart price.  Yes, you might round that to $0.98$